# Can not join more than two table

Tags: mysql, sql, double, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

```
table1

fields : id, title, cat1_id

table2

fields : id, title, cat2_id

table3 

fields : id, title
```

My SQL :

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, b.title, c.title 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON b.id = a.cat1_id 
AND INNER JOIN table3 AS c ON c.id = b.cat2_id 
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

it's not working.

I try this SQL, it's working:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, b.title, c.title 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON b.id = a.cat1_id 
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

but double `INNER JOIN` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `AND` before `JOIN` to join more that two tables.

Your query should be

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, b.title, c.title 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON b.id = a.cat1_id 
INNER JOIN table3 AS c ON c.id = b.cat2_id 
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Have a look at [MySQL `JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

Comment: I am searching answer for a few hours, just little **"AND"** thanks for help. :)